# How to set the minimum value for time difference?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If the time difference between departure time and arrival time is less than less than 30 minutes or negative, how to assume the value to be 30 ?

For example, I have the following datatype:

```
id         departure time             arrival time         start  end  capacity

Train A   2016-05-19 01:45:00       2016-05-19 08:25:00   A     G    2
Train A   2016-05-19 16:54:00       2016-05-19 16:00:00   B     H    2
Train A   2016-05-19 21:25:00       2016-05-20 07:25:00   C     I    3
Train B   2016-05-24 02:20:00       2016-05-24 12:50:00   D     J    3
Train B   2016-05-24 18:30:00       2016-05-25 20:00:00   E     K    2
Train B   2016-05-26 19:35:00       2016-05-26 19:45:00   F     L    3
```

I use the following formula to find the time difference

```
df['time difference'] = ((df['departure time'] - df['arrival time']).abs())
```

I want to set the minimum value of time difference to be 30, )if the value is less than 30 or negative)

Comment: Why are you doing a groupby?

Comment: removed it!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract columns and convert to minutes by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide `60` first and then replace to 30 by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
diff = (df['departure time'] - df['arrival time']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
df['time difference'] = diff.mask(diff < 30, 30)
print (df)
        id      departure time        arrival time start end  capacity  \
0  Train A 2016-05-19 01:45:00 2016-05-19 08:25:00     A   G         2   
1  Train A 2016-05-19 16:54:00 2016-05-19 16:00:00     B   H         2   
2  Train A 2016-05-19 21:25:00 2016-05-20 07:25:00     C   I         3   
3  Train B 2016-05-24 02:20:00 2016-05-24 12:50:00     D   J         3   
4  Train B 2016-05-24 18:30:00 2016-05-25 20:00:00     E   K         2   
5  Train B 2016-05-26 19:35:00 2016-05-26 19:45:00     F   L         3   

   time difference  
0             30.0  
1             54.0  
2             30.0  
3             30.0  
4             30.0  
5             30.0
```

Comment: Hello ! i have few data that gives negative time difference . in that case no value gets stored. Do you know how to replace null values with 30 minutes ?? thank you!

Comment: the negative value is due to minor error in data (though negative difference in time isnt possible)

Comment: i was having null value in the difference difference, and i assumed that it might be because of negative value. i will check if there are any other reasons for this null value

Comment: Try check `df['new'] = diff` for new column with difference.

Comment: you know u can compare directly vs a Timedelta rather than use .total_seconds()

Comment: @jezrael problem solved ! it works ! and thank you ! ^^

Comment: @jezrael can you help me with this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567263/how-to-solve-the-following-condition

Comment: I am going on it, but not so easy :)

Comment: thank you so much ! i have been stuck with this problem as well !