# How to solve the following condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data type:

```
id      point 1    point 2      count            Time             
018     Paris      London        01      2016-05-20 10:50:00      
015     Paris      London        01      2016-05-19 11:50:00      
002     Prague     Munich        15      2016-05-18 17:55:00      
003     Frankfurt  London        01      2016-05-17 21:15:00      
015     London     Paris         08      2016-05-21 13:50:00      
003     Barcelona  Vienna        15      2016-05-19 03:20:00      
003     London     Barcelona     01      2016-05-18 06:45:00      
002     Vienna     Prague        15      2016-05-19 02:45:00
```

I would like to group them by id and time first,

```
df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])
```

to get these reult:

```
id      point 1    point 2      count            Time      
002     Vienna     Prague        15      2016-05-18 02:45:00 
002     Prague     Munich        15      2016-05-18 17:55:00
003     Frankfurt  London        01      2016-05-17 21:15:00 
003     London     Barcelona     01      2016-05-18 06:45:00  
003     Barcelona  Vienna        15      2016-05-19 03:20:00 
015     Paris      London        01      2016-05-19 11:50:00
015     London     Paris         08      2016-05-21 13:50:00 
018     Paris      London        01      2016-05-20 10:50:00
```

If point 2 of first line and point 1 of second line is same, then start is point 1 of first line and end id point 2 of second line.[id 002]

but, if point 2 of first line is same as point 1 in second line AND point 1 of first line is same as point 2 of first line, then start and end does not change.[id 015]

Result:

```
id      point 1    point 2      count            Time            Start     End
002     Vienna     Prague        15      2016-05-19 02:45:00    Vienna   Munich
002     Prague     Munich        15      2016-05-18 17:55:00    Vienna   Munich
003     Frankfurt  London        01      2016-05-17 21:15:00    Frankfurt Vienna
003     London     Barcelona     01      2016-05-18 06:45:00    Frankfurt Vienna
003     Barcelona  Vienna        15      2016-05-19 03:20:00    Frankfurt Vienna
015     Paris      London        01      2016-05-19 11:50:00    Paris     London
015     London     Paris         08      2016-05-21 13:50:00    London   Paris
018     Paris      London        01      2016-05-20 10:50:00    Paris    London
```

I tried the first condition, using :

```
 df = df.assign(start = np.where(df['point2'] == df['point1'].shift(),df.shift(1).point2,df.point1))
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have the first step?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you stuck on?

Comment: How are you representing the data?

Comment: i will update what i have tried..

Comment: _I would like to group them by id and time first,_


What do you mean group by time? Because your "sorted" list has some dates sorted in ascending order and some in descending order.

Comment: ascending order.. using : df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])

Comment: But then the line with point 1 = Prague and point 2 = Munich ends up above the other line with id=2, so their points 1 and 2 don't match up... (if that makes sense)

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. i made the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) in custom function:

```
#sort values first
df = df.sort_values(['id','Time'])
#create new columns
df['Start'] = df['point 1']
df['End'] = df['point 2']

def f(x):

    #roll values of point 2 and compare with point 1 per groups
    #all function for scalar True if all values are True
    m = (np.roll(x['point 2'].values, -1) != x['point 1']).all()
    if m:
        #assign first and last values
        x['Start'] = x['point 1'].iat[0]
        x['End'] = x['point 2'].iat[-1]
    return x

#apply custom function
df = df.groupby('id').apply(f)
print (df)
    id    point 1    point 2 count                Time      Start     End
7  002     Vienna     Prague    15 2016-05-19 02:45:00     Vienna  Munich
2  002     Prague     Munich    15 2016-05-19 17:55:00     Vienna  Munich
3  003  Frankfurt     London    01 2016-05-17 21:15:00  Frankfurt  Vienna
6  003     London  Barcelona    01 2016-05-18 06:45:00  Frankfurt  Vienna
5  003  Barcelona     Vienna    15 2016-05-19 03:20:00  Frankfurt  Vienna
1  015      Paris     London    01 2016-05-19 11:50:00      Paris  London
4  015     London      Paris    08 2016-05-21 13:50:00     London   Paris
0  018      Paris     London    01 2016-05-20 10:50:00      Paris  London
```

Comment: Super, glad can help!